# Can't we access our jersey api without using jerseyclient api

Tags: jersey-2.0

I want to build my website like naukri.com (not exactly) but concept may match.

Currently I am writing API using jersey and consuming those API's directly from front end using AJAX request.

Do I need to write jersey client here as well, if so how that will help me out. Pls let me know, Why we need to write client if we are able to consume API's directly using ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a special client in order to interact with RESTful services.  That's one of the main things that is appealing about them.  There is no requirement to build anything with jersey client in order to host services with jersey.

You would build a client library if you want to make it easy for people to interact with your APIs from something an application.  If this isn't something you need or want to do, you don't have to do it.  Another use case would be for testing but there's no reason you have to build the client with jersey just because you built the server with jersey.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't need jersey client, you already have client to call/consume API's at front-end i suppose, you will need jersey client if you want to call/consume your services at server-side to write test cases for example, something like this -

```
Client client = Client.create();

WebResource webResource = client
           .resource("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/get");

        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                   .get(ClientResponse.class);
```